# print preview table bad stacking?

Tags: html, css, html-table, page-break

I have table with many row. It's too long for the snippet so i provide the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxqg1ys6/2/)  . Basically is html table with many row and structured with

```
<table>
<thead>text here!</thead>
<tbody>
inside this is td with many tr structure, rowspan and colspan
</tbody>
```

All i want is :

- Thead always appear on the top of the print paper
- i want automatically page break of the first tr (MODEL as the starter td)

I already has the solution for the first problem, but why it's look so ugly (some td has stacking problem on the next paper) and get inside the thead? i confused with this...

[image: The problem]

And if possible, is there any solution for page-break? i already searching all the answer but it must done manually to the which tr should on another page. But i want to automatically doing page break on start tr of MODEL

Thank you, i know my question is basic... but i really stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try scaling out your page using the `@page` property of CSS3

Your code would somewhat look like this

```
@media print {
@page {
size: 21cm 29.7cm;
margin: 30mm 45mm 30mm 45mm;
}
tr,td { page-break-before: always; }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However it still has the sampe problem for bad stacking